# What is required for the "required" attribute on HTML input elements to work?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, react-bootstrap

I have this component, using react, react-bootstrap, and bootstrap. I'm guessing it might be bad practice to mix all these dependencies, but the reason I am using react-bootstrap is because I want to use their modal functionality, which uses js, instead of vanilla bootstrap's jQuery. Here is my component:

```
        <Modal size="lg" show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
              <Modal.Title>Create Freelancer Account</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <form>
              <Modal.Body>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label>University</label>
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" name="University" onChange={handleInputChange} required />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label>Student ID</label>
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" name="StudentID" onChange={handleInputChange} required />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label>Major(s)</label>
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" name="Major" onChange={handleInputChange} required />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label>Skills</label>
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" name="Skills" onChange={handleInputChange} required />
                </div>
              </Modal.Body>
              <Modal.Footer>
                <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
                  Close
                </Button>
                <Button type="submit" variant="primary" onClick={handleSubmit}>
                  Submit
                </Button>
              </Modal.Footer>
            </form>
        </Modal>
```

I have enclosed the entire section that includes the inputs and the button in a form tag, since from my research those need to be encapsulated together for the required to work. However, when I click the button, it still submits, even when the form is empty. What is wrong here?

Comment: Is your form submission handled by `handleSubmit`? If so, the form is submitted on button click, not an actual submission. Try `onsubmit` instead of `onclick`.

Comment: ^^ as above, but just to clarify, it's the `onsubmit` of the form.

Comment: Yes, the submit is handled by handleSubmit. All it does is send a POST request and redirect to another page. I tried putting ```onsubmit``` on the form and I removed the onclick from the button, but now it does not do anything.